# Ext js 6: Grid doesn't show all fields for new inserted item

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs-grid, extjs-stores

I have following model and store.

Model:

```
Ext.define('TruckTask.model.Company', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

idProperty: 'id',

fields: [
    {name: 'id',  type: 'int', defaultValue: null},
    {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
    {name: 'site',  type: 'string'},
    {name: 'createdDate',  type: 'date',
        convert: function(rawValue, model) {

    var intDate = parseInt(rawValue);

            if(intDate > 0){
                return Ext.util.Format.date(new Date(intDate), 'd.m.Y');
            }

            if(typeof(rawValue) == 'object'){
                return rawValue;
            }
        }
    },
    {name: 'langId',  type: 'int'}
]
```

});

Store:

```
Ext.define('TruckTask.store.Company', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires : [
    'TruckTask.model.Company',
    'TruckTask.config.SecureRestProxy'
],

alias: 'store.company',

storeId: 'company',

model   : 'TruckTask.model.Company',

autoLoad: true,
autoSync: true,

proxy: {
    type: 'secure-rest',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    },
    api: {
        read: '/api/company',
        create: '/api/company',
        update: '/api/company',
        destroy: '/api/company'
    }
}
```

});

I use grid panel for list of this models. But creation of new model I make through another form.

In grid I define store:

```
    store: {
    type: 'company'
},
```

and form's submit handler has implementation:

```
var record = this.getViewModel().get('rec');
    var companyStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('company');
    companyStore.add(record);
```

So the record appears in grid panel immediately, but without createdDate field value. This value comes from server response.

How can I update this record in grid panel when I get server response?

Comment: It should do so automatically. If it doesn't, please make a minimal verifyable example exhibiting the problem.

Comment: Yes, I expect such behaviour, but actually I'm even not able to click on the new added row. It's presented in grid, but couldn't be selected, when I click on it. Could it be connected with my trick to avoid model's id, that are generated by ext js. Please, look at  add event listener in the store. When I add new record to store, it get id by template <ModelName>-<order>. And I get error on server side.

Comment: I had a similar behaviour when using a grid with grouping, caused by an ExtJS bug. Do you use grouping in your grid?

Comment: No, I don't use

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022616/store-do-something-after-sync-with-autosync-enabled) useful. Implement the *onCreateRecords* on your store and set whatever needs to be set after new records has been created and saved.